# Почему возникают коллизии?

Tags: java, хеширование

Как известно, ситуация, когда у разных объектов одинаковые хеш-коды называется — коллизией. Вероятность возникновения коллизии зависит от используемого алгоритма генерации хеш-кода.

Но вот вопрос, почему она возникает? Неужели тяжко придумать "защиту" от возникновения коллизии?
Кто что думает?

Comment: Результат хеш-функции может быть короче ее аргумента. Коллизий избежать невозможно.

Comment: Вообще, есть [perfect hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) ([идеальная хэш-функция](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%98%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%85%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))

Comment: *Вероятность возникновения коллизии зависит от используемого алгоритма генерации хеш-кода.* Нет. Если алгоритмы хэширования не содержат статистических, математических и прочих погрешностей, вероятность коллизии зависит только от длины формируемого хэша.

Comment: *Неужели тяжко придумать "защиту" от возникновения коллизии?* Да элементарно. Просто длина хэша должна быть не меньше максимальной длины хэшируемых данных (с учётом пэддинга).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Хеш код в java создается методом

```
  public int hashCode()
```

У integer диапазон от -2147483648 до 2147483647, т.е. округлив получаем 4 миллиарда разных целых чисел.

А теперь представим ситуацию, у вас 8-10 миллиардов объектов. Вопрос: как каждому из них дать уникальный хеш код используя диапазон в 4 миллиарда?

Ответ: никак.

При этом вы не знаете сколько объектов вашего класса могут создать пользователи.

Если ваш класс будет использоваться в Hash структурах как ключ, вы так же должны постараться обеспечить объекты такими хеш кодами, чтобы они попадали в разные корзины и получить равномерное заполнение структуры.